# В gitlab не работает авторизация через LDAP, при добавлении удалённого репозитория

Tags: git, gitlab, active-directory, ldap

### Настроил в gitlab авторизацию через ldap

вот настройки

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-EOS # remember to close this block with 'EOS' below
main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
    label: 'LDAP'
    host: 'host'
    port: 389
    uid: 'uid'
    method: 'plain'
    bind_dn: 'bind_dn'
    password: 'password'
    active_directory: true
    allow_username_or_email_login: true
    base: 'DC=a,DC=b,DC=c'
    user_filter: ''
EOS
```

Потом отключил возможность авторизации и регистрации стандартным методом, командой в gitlab-rails console

```
ApplicationSetting.last.update_attributes(password_authentication_enabled_for_web: false)
```

### На веб морде получился такой результат

[image: окно авторизации]

### Через веб всё отлично, но когда пытаюсь добавить репозиторий на другой машине

```
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/rep.git
git fetch
```

Логин и пароль почему то не подходит!
git fetch
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я упустил?

Answer (score 0):

allow_username_or_email_login: true
это настройка должна обрезать email до логина, тоесть если вы вводите в логин bogdan@mail.ru то в ldap улетает только bogdan.
Но это почему то работает только в веб морде, через терминал нужно писать просто bogdan.
facepalm